# Recvoring prices from a site?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

I was in the process of recovering prices in website

Here is my php code

```
<?php 

$adresse1 = "http://fr.camping-and-co.com/location-camping-angles-85750?           pagination=18&_ct=1&_rg=118&_dpt=all&_dt=7&_st=09%2F07%2F2016&_hbc=1&_pn=all&chx=&ox=&ctxy=46.387539%2C-1.399005%2C40&rgx=&stx=&scx=&thx=&pmin=1&pmax=6000&page=1&tri=&order=";
   $page1 = file_get_contents ($adresse1); // récupérer le contenu de la          page      
   preg_match_all('/partir de(.*)€/',$page1,$matches);  

      for($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++) 
    {
     echo "====================>".$matches[0][$i];   
      echo "</br>" ;
   }

  ?>
```

the problem that in  the site  there are some prices that are deleted and not respect the rule that i put in my expression rule

Here is the site :
       http://fr.camping-and-co.com/location-camping-angles-85750?pagination=18&_ct=1&_rg=118&_dpt=all&_dt=7&_st=09%2F07%2F2016&_hbc=1&_pn=all&chx=&ox=&ctxy=46.387539%2C-1.399005%2C40&rgx=&stx=&scx=&thx=&pmin=1&pmax=6000&page=1&tri=&order=

I want to recover all prices !

but this script recover all price in this format:

```
 à partir de 639 € / 7 nuits
```

but not those with this format :

```
 à partir de -20% 729 € 585 € / 7 nuits
```

Comment: do you need **[partir de(.*?)€](https://regex101.com/r/mZ6pT1/1)**?

Comment: @rock321987 what i need to recover all prices  in the site for exemple 639   , 585  coz 729 is deleted

Comment: this is the site :

Comment: http://fr.camping-and-co.com/location-camping-angles-85750?pagination=18&_ct=1&_rg=118&_dpt=all&_dt=7&_st=09%2F07%2F2016&_hbc=1&_pn=all&chx=&ox=&ctxy=46.387539%2C-1.399005%2C40&rgx=&stx=&scx=&thx=&pmin=1&pmax=6000&page=1&tri=&order=

Comment: there are prices and and i want to recover all prices

Comment: Use DOMDocument and DOMXPath, not a regex.

Comment: what are the rules you are expecting them to follow?

Comment: @rock321987 the rules all string that start with  à partir de  and the end € so i can recover the price but this dont  work with those type of prices à partir de -20% 729 € 585 € / 7 nuits and it work with those type of prices  à partir de 639 € / 7 nuits what i need to recover prices

Comment: if i understood correctly, check **[this](https://regex101.com/r/mZ6pT1/2)**

Comment: @rock321987 i just used this and it d'ont work  preg_match_all('/partir de(.*\D)(\d+ €)/',$page1,$matches);

Comment: match is in `$matches[2]`

Comment: check **[here](http://ideone.com/rLgtnd)**

Comment: for($i=0;$i<count($matches[1]);$i++)   
{    
echo "====================>".$matches[1][$i];   
echo "</br>" ;
}  yes i used this @rock321987 and it don't work

Comment: see **[here](http://ideone.com/uQQqyF)**
`$str` is equivalent to `$page1`

Comment: @rock321987 when i use your code with your string exemple it work but when i use mine this code  it show me this error Notice: Undefined offset:  my be coz the orgin of my string is $page1 = file_get_contents ($adresse1)

Comment: my string in which i work it is the contained of all site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a regular expression you should use a DOMDocument and look for the prices you want to retrieve by selecting all those having the matching css class `price`:

```
$adresse1 = "http://fr.camping-and-co.com/location-camping-angles-85750?pagination=18&_ct=1&_rg=118&_dpt=all&_dt=7&_st=09%2F07%2F2016&_hbc=1&_pn=all&chx=&ox=&ctxy=46.387539%2C-1.399005%2C40&rgx=&stx=&scx=&thx=&pmin=1&pmax=6000&page=1&tri=&order=";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($adresse1);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('//*[@class="price"]');

/** @var DOMElement $price */
foreach ($elements as $price) {
    echo "====================>" . $price->textContent;
    echo "</br>\n";
}
```

Comment: it's working @joachim Schirrmacher thx but it show me ====================>528Â â‚¬ 
====================>606Â â‚¬     Â â‚¬  in the end how can i delete this

Comment: You get an empty price tag as the last entry? That's strange because there is no such element on the page. Do you have a public available url which shows the output of your script?